# Netty Client Streaming Data channelRead0 never called

Tags: netty, http2

I am new to Netty. I need to process a stream of messages from a server that supports HTTP2.  I followed along with the Baeldung tutorials, but those had a client that sent a GET request and received a "hello world" response and that was the end of the example.

I need to listen for an endless stream of responses from the client's server.  I setup the same way as the sample code and also had a logger running that would show me [INBOUND|OUTBOUND]_SETTINGS,[INBOUND|OUTBOUND]_HEADERS, [INBOUND|OUTBOUND]_DATA.  The INBOUND_DATA that I expected was received, but it showed endStream=false.

The implementation of the SimpleClientInboundHandler did not get called after one or more messages were received.  I changed things to call a different API that did not provide a streaming response.  The response came in three parts. The first two had endStream=false, the last endStream=true in the logging. It worked as expected, with channelRead0 being called after the complete message was received.

I know this may be kind of vague, but is there a way to have Netty process the first message that is received?  I tried Object and ByteBuff for received content.  All seemed to be waiting for a "full" FullHttpResponse message.